# In Excel how can I return all the text value that are not found in an original column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

i  have two columns in Excel (Column A and B , going left to right), like so:

```
column A             Column B
ACT CNSCHK           ACT DIAMDICTXML
ACT DXCLNK           ACT DM
ACT IUALNK           ACT DMLKS
ACT LICENSE          ACT DMLNK
ACT M2UALNK          ACT CNSCHK
ACT M3ASSO           ACT DXCLNK
ACT M3ASSOS          ACT LICCTL
```

And I'd like to get all the items from Column B that are not in Column A: i.e i want to know that text value ACT DM, ACT DMLNK, ACT DMLKS of column B not exist in column A and that missing text will be highlight as a different colour.
I know I need VLOOKUP() , however I'm a bit lost on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you could just use countif
eg in column C put `=COUNTIF(A:A,B1)`
then use filtering if column C =0 the entry in column B doesn't exist in column A